# Python: Parsing Excel Data with Nested Groupings into a Dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, parsing, nested-groups

I'm trying to parse an Excel sheet that contains product quantities for different rooms in various units of a building. The data is structured hierarchically: each building unit contains multiple rooms, and each room has multiple products with quantities.

The Excel data looks like this:

| group | Assembly Name | Item Name | Size | Part number | List Price | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bld 16 Unit 1A |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bedroom 1 WIC WALL A |  |  |  |  | ### | ### |
|  | 12-1S-1R-6 | item | size | ########## | ### | # |
|  | 12-1S-1R-6 | item | size | ########## | ### | # |
| Bedroom 1 WIC WALL B |  |  |  |  | ### | ## |
|  | 12-1S-1R-6 | item | size | ########## | ### | # |
| Bedroom 2 RIC |  |  |  |  | ### | ## |
|  | 12-1S-1R-6 | item | size | ########## | ### | # |

I want to transform this data into a dictionary structure like:

```
{
    ('Building 16', 'Unit 1A'): {
        'Bedroom 1 WIC': {'item1': qty1, 'item2': qty2, ...},
        'Bedroom 2 WIC': {'item1': qty1, 'item2': qty2, ...},
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I've written a function to parse this data, but I'm encountering an issue where the quantities for the first room are not captured correctly. Instead, the data for the first room is being associated with the second room, and so on.

here's the function:

```
def collect_data(df, products, room_wall_codes):
    data_collection = {}
    current_building = None
    current_unit = None
    room_data = []
    current_room_data = initialize_product_dict(products)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        # Detect a new unit
        if "Bld" in row['Group'] or "Building" in row['Group']:
            # Save the previous unit's data if available
            if current_building and current_unit:
                data_collection[(current_building, current_unit)] = room_data
                room_data = []
            current_building, current_unit = extract_building_and_unit(row['Group'])
            continue

        # Detect a new room
        if pd.isna(row['Item Name']):
            # Save the previous room's data
            if current_room_data:
                room_data.append(current_room_data)
                current_room_data = initialize_product_dict(products)
            continue

        # Collect product data for the current room
        if row['Item Name'] in current_room_data:
            current_room_data[row['Item Name']] += row['QTY']

    # Save the last room's data
    if current_room_data:
        room_data.append(current_room_data)

    # Save the last unit's data
    if current_building and current_unit:
        data_collection[(current_building, current_unit)] = room_data

    return data_collection
```

Can anyone help me identify what's causing this issue and how to fix it?

1. **Initial Approach**:

   - We started by creating a `collect_data` function to process the DataFrame and extract the necessary data.
   - The logic was to loop through the DataFrame and, based on the content of the 'Group' column, determine if we're encountering a new building, unit, or room.
   - We used a combination of flags and temporary variables (`current_building`, `current_unit`, etc.) to keep track of the current state.
   - The data was to be stored in a nested dictionary structure.

   **Outcome**: The first room's data was being skipped, and the data was shifted (i.e., the second room had the first room's data, the third room had the second room's data, and so on).
2. **Debugging**:

   - We added print statements to debug the data collection process.
   - We verified that `combined_output` (which contains room-wall-codes) was in the correct order.
   - We printed the keys of the `data_collection` dictionary to ensure that the building and unit names were being captured correctly.

   **Outcome**: We identified that the logic for detecting a new unit was flawed, especially for the first unit.
3. **Revised Logic**:

   - We revised the logic for detecting new units and rooms.
   - We tried to ensure that when a new unit is detected, the data for the previous unit is saved, and then the counters are reset for the new unit.
   - We also took into account the possibility of different naming conventions for buildings (e.g., "Bld" vs. "Building").

   **Outcome**: The issue persisted, with the first room's data still being skipped.
4. **Further Debugging**:

   - We revisited the logic for saving data, especially when encountering a new unit.
   - We discussed the structure of the input data, particularly the order in which rooms and their data appear.

   **Outcome**: We identified that the logic for saving data when encountering a new unit was still flawed, especially for the first unit.
5. **Revised Data Saving Logic**:

   - We attempted to modify the logic to save data that comes after detecting a new unit, rather than before.

   **Outcome**: The issue persisted.

Throughout this process, we've been trying to ensure that the data is captured correctly for each room within each unit. The primary challenge has been the order in which data appears in the DataFrame and ensuring that the logic correctly captures and assigns data to the right room and unit.

Comment: Sorry in advance if I’m missing key points but this feels like overkill. 

My preference would always be to flatten the data. 

I would get the data into a data frame with ‘pd.read_excel’ making use of the ‘header’ argument and use ‘df.ffill()’ to drag grouping columns down. Then filter rows with null values in the 
product quantities (don’t ffill these). Now you should have a dataframe you can manipulate with ‘df.to_dict()’ to get the desired output.

Comment: Please can you also provide a screen shot of the excel so that the column indexes (A-Z) can be seen. Mainly in relation to ‘group’ … is this multi column or indenting.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'm trying your first suggestion atm. I'm new with stackoverflow so i'm not sure how to post a screen shot, however the first code example is the excel data and the group column is indented.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think indenting makes it more tricky. Is it xlsx format or something else?

Comment: To post a screen shot simply use 'print screen' then paste into the editing window. However you should trim the image as much as possible to better to use 'alt-print screen' to copy just the Excel sheet and then use MS Paint or something similar to crop the image down to the necessary part(s) before copying then pasting that image into the editing area. Since you appear to be working with a Dataframe it would probably have been more useful to include that as text in you question as well.